# ATmega328p motor circuit resetting the controller

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, dc-motor, atmega328p

I've made a circuit to run a 5V DC motor via ATmega328p  microcontroller GPIO as shown below.  When the 5V DC motor is connected and the controller tries to actuate the motor, the microcontroller will reset. If there is no motor connection, the relay will br actuated properly. The power supply circuit is also provided. Please let me know how to resolve this.

[image: Power supplycircuit]

[image: Motor circuit]

[image: microcontroller circuit]

Comment: How much current does the motor pull when starting?

Comment: What is your input power source?  Probably you are overloading it causing a brownout...

Comment: Like Chris said, your motor is probably overloading your power supply with its starting current.  You could try "huge capacitor" and hope it gives you enough charge to ride through.  There's also inrush current limiters, which are resistors that will reduce the current drawn by the motor for a while as they heat up and eventually lower their resistance.  You could also swap out the BC548 for a logic level MOSFET and implement a ramped PWM startup in software.

Comment: operating current of this motor is around 220 mA.  i do not see any inrush current specified in the motor datasheet its just a water pump. because of this i placed a dedicated voltage regulator for this which can withstand upto 1A. now I'll try a larger capacitor at the output side of the voltage regulator. will it help?

Comment: @AnilSuha I'd try adding a large electrolytic bulk capacitor at the point where the power enters the board (DC jack). Say 1000µF as an initial test.

Comment: I had a similar design many years ago, controlling a windshield wiper with a PIC. The motor took about 1A while operating, but more than 10A on start-up. My error was that both PCB lines to and from the motor framed the µC circuit, building a single-loop inductor. That inrush current gave enough induced voltage to reset the µC. The solution was to relocate the lines aside to each other.

Comment: @Unimportant :I tried using 1000uF electrolytic cap . but the result did not changed.

Comment: Are D10 and D9 installed? They must be

Comment: @ Russell McMahon:Yes, both of them.

Comment: I'm using a wall adapter 12-5V /2A . and in some videos they are using Laptop SMPS adapter(similar rating). whats the difference? may be i should add a huge cap of around 1000uF at the input to minimize the noise and at the output of LM7805 also i should increase the value of cap.

Comment: Have you solved It? I am facing same problem!